# Unity model in Angular app not caching in browser when deployed in Azure

Tags: angular, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

We have a legacy project with a unity WebGL viewer hosted in MVC and it loads sloowly the first time, but after that, it's quite fast due to caching.  However, our updated version in angular13 (deployed in Azure) is not taking advantage of the caching, so it's very very slow every time we load the page.  The new app has 2 WebGL build files (.data and .wasm extension) and caches fine when run locally.  Is there maybe something needed in the web.config file for deployment that would enable the caching?

We're using a unity version 2021.3.18f1 and below are the player settings option we are using to build : -

WebGL Template : Minimal
Data Caching : Enabled
Compression Format : Disabled